# Concatenate/Merge vectors in single vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

My map function giving me output:

```
([[:db/retract 1 :a 23] [:db/retract 1 :b 34]] [[:db/retract 2 :v 45] [:db/retract 2 :o 89]] [[:db/retract 4 :l 6]])
```

But I want these like :

```
([[:db/retract 1 :a 23] [:db/retract 1 :b 34] [:db/retract 2 :v 45] [:db/retract 2 :o 89][:db/retract 4 :l 6]])
```

How we should merge the vectors in single vector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given

```
(def v '([[:db/retract 1 :a 23] [:db/retract 1 :b 34]] [[:db/retract 2 :v 45] [:db/retract 2 :o 89]] [[:db/retract 4 :l 6]]))
```

you can use

```
(apply concat v)
```

to get

```
([:db/retract 1 :a 23] [:db/retract 1 :b 34] [:db/retract 2 :v 45] [:db/retract 2 :o 89] [:db/retract 4 :l 6])
```

---

If you really need the inner vector inside a list, use

```
`(~(vec (apply concat v)))
```

to get

```
([[:db/retract 1 :a 23] [:db/retract 1 :b 34] [:db/retract 2 :v 45] [:db/retract 2 :o 89] [:db/retract 4 :l 6]])
```